# "Mapping" a function over a set to create another set

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, set, mapping

In a functional language, if you have `S`, a set whose elements have type `T`, and `f`, a function `: T -> U`, you can write `map f S` (or some language-specific version of that) to create a set of `U`s.

Is it possible to achieve something similar in C++11 using `for_each` or some other STL constructs?

Comment: What you are doing is basically [transforming](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) one set to another.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::set<U> SetOfUs;
std::transform(S.begin(), S.end(), std::inserter(SetOfUs, SetOfUs.begin()), f);
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to write it functionally, and in particular have the  set<U> be declared const rather than modifying it...

Comment: Write a function that does this in its implementation, then returns `SetOfUs` by value.

Comment: I was checking whether I was missing some standard library fn that did this -- looks like the answer is 'no'.